# Real analytic function of one variable with given set of values

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analytic-structures

Given two strictly increasing bounded sequences of reals $x_n$ and $y_n$. What is known about existence of real analytic function $f$ with property $f(x_{n_k})=y_{n_k}$ for some subsequence $x_{n_k}$ ?

**Edit 1:** Of course, $y_n$ can't increase too slow or too fast relative to $x_n$ as it was shown in counterexamples below. So, we can additionally assume the following ($x=\sup x_n,~y=\sup y_n$):

$0<\underline\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x_n-x|}{|y_n-y|},~ \overline\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x_n-x|}{|y_n-y|}<\infty$

or even:
$0<\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x_n-x|}{|y_n-y|}<\infty$ if needed.

**Edit 2:** Clear counterexample is given below. Can one suggest any sufficient conditions on $x_n, y_n$ for existence of $f$ ?

Comment: What requirements on the domain of $f$? Should it include $\sup x_n$? (I guess $f$ locally constant on a disconnected open set is not what you want)

Comment: $f$ must be defined in some open neighborhood of $sup x_n$

Comment: How about simply $x_n = 1-1/n$, $y_n = 1-1/\sqrt{n}$?  This would seem to ensure that such $f$ cannot even be differentiable at $1$.

Comment: @NateEldredge you are right. Question conditions were modified.

Answer (score 1):

It's not always possible to find such a function, for example take $x_n\to 0-$, $y_n=-e^{-1/x_n^2}$. A holomorphic function $f: D_r(0)\to\mathbb C$, $f\not\equiv 0$, would satisfy $|f(x)|\gtrsim |x|^k$ for some $k\ge 0$, so cannot satisfy $f(x_n)=y_n$ for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: Of course, you are right. I have added the condition to avoid your described situation

Comment: @ar.grig: This (your edit) won't help because the same phenomenon can also happen in higher order, say $y_n=x_n-e^{-1/x_n^2}$. (The $x_n,y_n$ have to be consistent with the approximation by Taylor polynomials of arbitrarily high order.)

Comment: Can you suggest the sufficient condition for existence of $f$?